# How do I not escape HTML special characters in QDomText?

Tags: html, c++, qt, html-escape-characters, qtxml

I'm trying to create an HTML document containing Javascript using Qt XML. Here is the relevant part of my Qt code:

```cpp
QDomDocument document;
//Create head, body, etc
QDomElement script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
body.appendChild(script);    //body is the QDomElement representing the <body> tag
QDomText scriptText = document.createTextNode("if(x < 0){\n/*do something*/\n}");
script.appendChild(scriptText);

QFile file("C:\\foo.html");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QTextStream stream(&file);
stream << document.toString();
```

The problem is that in the Javascript code, it's escaping the `<` character replacing it with `&lt;`, giving the following output which isn't valid Javascript:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(x &lt; 0){
        /*do something*/
    }
</script>
```

I've searched the Qt documentation for a solution, but haven't found anything.

A workaround could be to replace `&lt;` with `<` when writing in the file by doing `stream << document.toString().replace("&lt;", "<")`, but there might also be occurrences of `&lt;` outside of the Javascript code that I want to leave alone.

I can also think of a few Javascript tricks to check if a number is negative without using any special HTML characters, like for example `if(String(x).indexOf('-') != -1)`, but I would like to know if there is a better way of doing it.

My question is how do I create a `QDomText` object with text containing special HTML characters like `<`, `>`, `&`, etc without them being escaped in `QDomDocument::toString()`?

Comment: I'd use something more suitable (and faster) like [Grantlee](http://www.grantlee.org)? I have tried to use Qt XML to parse HTML and it's simply not meant for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the javascript code in a CDATA section:

```
  QDomElement script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
  body.appendChild(script);

  QString js = "if(x < 0){\n/*do something*/\n}";
  QDomCDATASection data = document.createCDATASection(js);
  script.appendChild(data);
```

then remove the unwanted text right after:

```
  QString text = document.toString();
  text.replace("<![CDATA[", "\n");
  text.replace("]]>", "\n");
```